# Laravel How to use hasManyThrough with groupBy?

Tags: laravel, resources

is there any way to count a group with a hasManyThrough in Laravel?
I have this database:

```
projects (id, project)
milestones (id, project_id,milestone)
todos (id,milestone_id,todo)
```

In my todos I am storing a employee. Now I want to know how many employees are working in project.

My Project Model looks like this:

```
public function employee()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough('App\Models\Todo', 'App\Models\Milestone');
}
```

My resource looks like this if I want to see all Todo in my Project:

```
'employee' => $this->employee()->get(),
```

How does my resource and/or model have to look like if I want to know how many employee are working in project. I tried something like this (not working):

```
'employee' => $this->employee()->groupBy('employee')->count(),
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  There are multiple ways of getting count of relational table
    Project::with(array('employee' => function($query) {
            $query->groupBy('employee')->count();
        }))
        ->get();
    Another way of getting relational count
    Project::withCount('employee')->get();
```

Comment: Thanks, but solution only counts all my todo. If a project has 4 todo and 2 employee are doing 2 todos, your solution is turning back 4, but should be 2.

Comment: Still i am confused you have 3 tables and you are trying to get todos using milestones table not employees. Just use Project::with(array('employee' => function($query) {
            $query->groupBy('milestone_id')->count();
        }))
        ->get();
because you are trying to fetch todos using milestone not employees. So groupby will be on milestone_id

Comment: Please take a look at my updated database structure.

Answer (score 0):

If you only has an employee for a todo, just use `withCount()`:

```php
$projects = Project::withCount(['employees' => function (Builder $query) {
    $query->where('employee_id', '!=', null);
}])->get();
```

And call `{relationship}_count` to show the result:

```php
foreach($projects as $project) {
   echo $project->employees_count;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but solution only counts all my todo. If a project has 4 todo and 2 employee are doing 2 todos, your solution is turning back 4, but should be 2.

Comment: You can use a closure to add condition for `withCount()`, i just update the answer